# Insert data using multiple components in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I am trying to insert data in database using multiple components in reactjs. In my first component I have a Form like below (there is not `Submit` button in this component)

```
render() {
return (
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"/>             
    </form>
);
```

}

In second component I am calling that component with `if` `else` logic.

In third component I have the submit button like below

```
<Button 
   positive icon='checkmark' 
   labelPosition='right' 
   onClick={this.insertAddress}
   content='Save' 
/>
```

My main issue is using `state`. How can I use `state` effectively here ? How can I catch the `input` values of first component in third component to insert in database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a parent container. The parent container holds the state, all the methods and event handlers. All of those are binding to the parent.

You then pass the methods and parts of the state down to the children. When they children use them, they will be changing the parent. I created a simple sandbox to demonstrate. You don't need to pass the entire state down, just the parts needed by the children.

https://codesandbox.io/s/q335wnjoyj

Comment: Thanks @Eddie Del Rio. Could you please explain this lines `let { name, value } = e.target;
    let state = { ...this.state };

    state[name] = value;` ?

Comment: we can name the input. I named it `value`. So we can use onChange for multiple inputs. If you have 3 inputs all with different names, and 3 state vlaues for each name, onChange will automatically choose the name,

Comment: I am getting error in this line. `let state = { ...this.state };` What does this line mean ?

Comment: That’s called a spread a spread operator. I’m using it to copy the state. Research them. But you never want to change the state. Instead, you copy the state. What error are you getting?

Comment: I know about spread operator. I have know more about all those things. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also ensure that the you have `this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);` in the constructor :D

Answer (score 0):

Use the concept of Container component.

create a container component which will hold the state of all you child components. keep updating all state related to Data in here. and call save functionality from here.

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
     constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
           name:'',
           email:'',
           phone:''
        }
        this.handleFormChanges = this.handleFormChanges.bind(this)
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.reactToSomeChange = this.reactToSomeChange.bind(this)
     }
      handleFormChanges(ev){
         // handle form and set appropriate state
      }
      handleFormChanges(ev){
         // react to change and set state
      }
      handleSubmit(){
         // update your data store db etc.
      }
      render(){
         return(
             <MyForm changes={this.handleFormChanges} />
             <IfElse changes={this.reactToSomeChange} />
             <Button submit={this.handleSubmit} />
         )
      }

}
// MyFrom component render function
   render() {
       return (
         <form>
           <input type="text" name="name" onChanges={this.props.changes} placeholder="Name"/>             
         </form>
        );
// Button component render function
 render(){
     <button onClick={this.props.submit}>SUBMIT<Button>

  }
```

Child components need not to call apis to save the data. it should be done from a single parent component that shares the same state in the child components.